# POST a Json object from an android app to localhost:9000 using play framework

Tags: android, json, rest, playframework-2.3

Well the title says pretty much what I want to do. How can I post a JSON Object to my localhost:9000 (which is started with play framework) from a button click in an Android app. 
 I have done the android method using AsyncTask to Post my JSON object and it works on other APIs. However, I am unsure on how to post it in my localhost:9000 because I want to use the latter as a REST API. Do I have to write something in the routes or configs files in play to be able to receive the JSON object?
For example,

```
GET           /someplace                     Controllers.applications.index()
```

If this helps, here is my method for executing the post in android asynctask:

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    JSONObject test = new JSONObject();
    try {
        test.put("Products", params[0]);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String send = test.toString();
    send = "Products=" + send;
    // localhost is my actual IP address
    executePost("http://<localhost>:9000/request",send);
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Yes! I am using the app with play-java

Answer (score 0):

You are using an external/internet ip address. For that you have to configure your router indeed. The router should forward the used port to the pc where your server runs. It is much easier to use the LAN address of the pc as then you don't have to forward. Find out LAN ip of pc with ipconfig.

Comment: In play, I want to be able to get what is sent from the android app. If I send it to <IP address>:9000 shouldn't I be posting with <IP address>:9000/someplace or do I need to create /someplace in play first?

Comment: Probably. But you choosed to use play. I know nothing of it. Sorry. Read the documents or search for examples.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to connect your app to localhost. An Easy way is to connect your computer with internet through you mobile (hotspot or tethering).
Open your terminal and run ifconfig and get the IP address provided by the usb connection (tethering). Use this IP instead of (localhost).

Comment: You are mixing tethering and usb connection. Makes no sense.

Comment: When I run ifconfig while tethering, the ip is provided by usb0. That's what I mean by usb connection.

Comment: Ok. That's different. But why should he tether? He probably has a (W)LAN. And connection to localhost is only possible with server and client on the same device. And he does not need internet for this.

Comment: This is one way. It's up to him. Connection to localhost from mobile device is possible the way I stated. I do it all the time.